# Power BI Bullet Chart Custom Visual Truncating Category Label

Tags: powerbi

Change the category values in the sample

let categoryValues = ["Total Category of Data", "Net Category of Data", "Gross Category of Data"];

You will see that overflow places elipsis where there is room for double the amount of label text leaving wasted white space and truncated label.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can override the default label width in code by setting
private static MaxLabelWidth = 180;

I changed it from 80 to 180

Comment: John, how to make change its?